# How many regions must $ \ T \ $ be split into in order to integrate some function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the tetrahedron $ \ T \ $ with vertices $ \ (1, 0, 0), (1, −1, 1), (1, 1, 1) \ \ and  \ \ (0, 0, 1) \ $. How many regions must $ \ T  \ $ be split into in order to integrate some function over T with the following variable orders ?

(i) $ dxdydz \ $

(ii) $ \ dxdzdy \ $

(iv) $ \ dydzdx \ $

**Answer:**

Suppose $ \ f(x,y,z) \ $ be any function over $ \ T \ $

(iv)

We have to integrate $ \ \iiint f(x,y,z) dxdydz \ $ over $ \ T \ $

Consider the plane containing the vertices $ \ (1,0,0) , \ (1,1,1) , \ (0,0,1) \ $ which is $ \ x-y+z=1 \ $

Thus the integration is

$ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{}^{} \int_{0}^{x+z-1} f(x,y,z) dxdzdy \ $

**Thus there is only one region for (iv)**

**Am I right ?**

Comment: This can't possibly be right, since you haven't even given a complete answer. What are the limits of integration for the middle integral? (And the order $dxdzdy$ in your answer seems to be the one for case (ii), not case (iv)?)

Comment: I am actually not quite clear about how many regions of integration is necessary meaning here ? Any help please so that I can understand the question as well.